# In websocket,how to prevent slow asyn response data incorrect modify

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm using websocket and I need to send request.

In my case, I send the first request and then I send a second request before I get the response for the first request.
The response for second request came back very quickly and then the response for the first request came.
At this moment, data from the later response modify the data incorrectly.

Is there any good ways to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want is to queue requests.

Simplest way is to simply fire the 2nd one after the 1st one returns.

A slightly more efficient mechanism is to fire both at the same time but keep track of which is which (this should be trivial).

Even better, if you can, is to create a route that returns both bits of data you require.

You mention something about the data being *wrong* somehow, this is unrelated to firing off multiple requests but maybe that is the real problem here?

Comment: Is there any good way to keep track of which is which? I'm passing id back and forth.

Comment: id works just fine, or you could stuff the responses into specific places in an array to keep order. There are lots of clever and/or simple ways to keep track, not sure there is a nailed-on one-size-fits-all best. id's sound just fine.